# Get Other People Facebook Post Using Hashtag in VB 2010

Tags: facebook, visual-studio-2010, twitter, filtering, hashtag

**

1. Help me guys i need a VB application that can search post by
   specific hashtag then save it into online or local database and also
   looking for twitter.

**

2. if you want to help me more ive been looking for free mysqldatabase hosting site and how to access it in vb application

Answer (score 1):

Starting with v2.0 of the Graph API, a search for public posts is no longer possible.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_graph_api

This means that you won't be able to search for hashtags in FB posts, unless you qualify for the special https://developers.facebook.com/docs/keyword_insights/ which is unlikely.